# dynamic class binding not working in angular 9

Tags: angular, ng-class

I need to display dynamic color for a div based on some condition. I am getting console error.

I have tried

```
<div [ngClass]="{'clr-{{students.rollNo+1}}': students.active}"></div>
```

students is my array, i have a class called .clr-5, clr-6 etc... in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<div [ngClass]="[ students.active ? 'clr-'+students.rollNo+1 : '']"></div>
```

class bindings are updated in Angular 9. [Read more about it here](https://angular.io/guide/style-precedence)

Comment: calculation not working clr-'+students.rollNo+1 need to add 1 with rollno

Comment: It will get concatenated with your dynamic value of roll number, here is an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/small-feather-0vk1z?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Comment: sorry cannot view this, white screen i can see!

Comment: if 25 is roll no then I need to add 25+1=26 should be the value not concatenation (251) Thanks!

Comment: you can try with creating a method  that returns your calculated value and then concatenate with class like this: 'clr-'+ addRollNumber(rollNo)

the method definition: 
addRollNumber(rollNo) {
    return rollNo + 1;
  }

Comment: yes it works , Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

string interpolation not work inside property binding. you should deal with that like:

```
<div [ngClass]="{`clr-${students.rollNo+1}`: students.active}"></div>
```

Comment: calculation not working clr-'+students.rollNo+1 need to add 1 with rollno